# How to auto redirect if my website is watching by usa to usa website instead of india website?

Tags: magento-1.9, url, redirect-url, countries

I have two websites.

1. India
2. USA

if my website is watching from India, no problem. India site will be displayed.

But when my website is watching from USA, i need to redirect my website to USA website. How can i do it?

Comment: You can use this extension : [Redirect Visitors by Country IP](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/redirect-visitors-by-country-ip.html)

Comment: did u ever tried this one !!

Comment: No. But this will work for you

Comment: https://screenshot.net/k1opeck

Comment: just now i am going to test my usa site.  if i accessed from india its not redirect to indian site. same usa site only visible.

Comment: redirect condition.

Comment: https://screenshot.net/jgrj0i2

Comment: @RohitKundale : Any Idea ?

Answer (score 0):

well you can use event and observer for that

```
controller_action_layout_load_before
```

and with in that event you can get visitor country from  their IP address

for that you can follow this post

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12553160/getting-visitors-country-from-their-ip

and redirect user to appropriate store on their country basis

Hope this will help you